# undefined method `protect_against_forgery?' for #<#<Class:0x0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have the following code in my routes.rb file .

```
resources :users  do
  member do
    get :following,:followers
  end
  collection do
    put :activate_email
  end
 end
```

And I have a user email activation link like this :

```
<%= link_to "Activate",activate_email_users_url(email_token: @user.email_token),method: :put  %>
```

When I click on the activate link , this is the url that is generated

```
 http://localhost:3000/users/activate_email?email_token=WWNvMN-r_lXgovrQiDlSSQ
```

Update: Ok, So I think I kno what the problem is . When I look at the html source of the activation email in my gmail which contains the link_to , there is no

```
data-method='put'
```

. So that seems to be the problem . It is always sending a default GET request instead of PUT.
This is my user_mailer/registration_confirmation.html.erb file

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
</head>
```

Please click on the following link to activate your email
  <%= link_to "Activate",activate_email_users_url(email_token: @user.email_token), method:     :put %>

This gives the following error :

```
undefined method `protect_against_forgery?' for #

So , the code <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

is causing this error. Is there any way around this ?

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want `post` or `put`, because you have them both in your question.

Comment: `put` is used when we want to update any data so to use `put` you need to create a `form` and not `link` with `put` as a method

Comment: I'm sorry ..I want 'put' . But 'post' doesnt work too. Just edited the question.

Comment: try `<%= link_to "Activate",activate_email_users_url(email_token: @user.email_token, _method: :put), method: :post  %>` and `put :activate_email`

Comment: Actually , in the link_to part, any method(post/put) is working if I use 'get :activate_email'. But if I use 'post :activate_email' or 'put :activate_email', it doesnt work.

Comment: I came across this in the Rails docs. --                              "Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified, so if you have a resources :photos above a get 'photos/poll' the show action’s route for the resources line will be matched before the get line. To fix this, move the get line above the resources line so that it is matched first"                                                       -- Does this have anything to do with my problem ?

Comment: First things first. What errors are given from your console logs.

Comment: It's not giving any errors . It is routing to the 'show' action of Users . Please look at the updated  question.

Comment: could you post your controller? (`show' action)

Comment: could, please, you show the whole stacktrace?

Comment: have you restart your server after changing the routes.rb?

Comment: sorry , my internet got cut . yes, I have restarted the server .where can i find the stacktrace ?

Comment: @ted I have updated question with full stack trace.

Comment: @anonymousxxx I have updated the question with the show action

Comment: @lnreddy, is it the right one? cannot see `app/controllers/users_controller.rb:16:in 'show'` line in it

Comment: @ted    app/controllers/users_controller.rb:16:in 'show'  That is the error I get . It's not the code in the 'show' action.

Comment: @lnreddy, absolutely. I meant I have not found that line in full stacktrace

Comment: @ted I cant find it in the full trace too . I have added a screenshot in the question .

Comment: @lnreddy, is that application stacktrace?

Comment: @ted No, its the "full trace"

Comment: @lnreddy, could you show the one from the app?

Comment: @ted sorry, I don't know how to get the app trace. Can you tell me the command ?

Comment: @lnreddy, on the screen that's on screenshot you've put in your post you can click on 'Application Trace'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, I do not know your purpose, but apparently you have a purpose to activate user.
Try this, if this solution not work, please tell me your action (activate_email) on controller!

see on `rake routes` output :

`activate_email_users PUT    /users/activate_email(.:format) users#activate_email`
`user GET    /users/:id(.:format)            users#show`

when your generate

`http://localhost:3000/users/activate_email?email_token=WWNvMN-r_lXgovrQiDlSSQ`

Your problem was `activate_email` considered to be `:id`

`users/activate_email => users/:id`

And solution for your problem :

Try removing the `method` from the link. Its better specifying the `method` in your routes file. How about replacing match by put in routes as :

```
resources :users  do
  member do
    get :following,:followers
  end
end
put "/users/activate_email/:email_token" => "users#activate_email", :as => "activate"
```

and on view

```
<%= link_to "Activate", activate_path(:email_token => @user.email_token)  %>
```

I have not tested this, but I guess this will suffice.

**UPDATE**

**for Question : undefined method `protect_against_forgery?'**

Add this to a helper that only your mailer template uses:

```
 def protect_against_forgery?
      false
 end
```

**NOTE** : If You have new question, please create new "Ask Question" and aprrove answer is usefull for this question

Comment: The data-method and other rails inbuilt html like "data-method='put'" is not showing up in my activation email in gmail.

Comment: Thanks for the help,I have updated my question .Could you take a look ?

Comment: I updated my answer, please if you have new questions, don't edit this question, you could create new "Ask Question" and approve an answer usefull..

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't aware of the rules. Is it safe to set protect_against_forgery to false ?

Comment: Where I should define `protect_against_forgery?`?

Comment: @RodrigoChaves in helper section.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to activate a single user account you probably don't want to be specifying your route on the collection (which you would use for actions that operate on multiple users).

Here's some (untested) code that should point you in the right direction:

```
controller :users do
    put '/activate/:email_token', :to => :activate,  :as => 'activate_email'
end
```

Which should route a PUT to `/activate/xxxx` to the `UsersController#activate` action with a `params[:email_token]` set as `xxxx`. It should also give you a `#activate_email_url` route which you can pass the activation token (you can check what routes your app provides by running `rake routes` on the command line).

Comment: I tried : put '/activate/:email_token', :to => :activate_email,  :as => 'activate_email'                                                      But it still routes to 'show' action .

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of `routes.rb` and `rake routes`. Also have you read the [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)?

Comment: I have added the routes.rb file too . And yes , I have read the routing guide, but I'm not very good at it(as you can see).

Answer (score 0):

Google redirected me to this question even-though mine was related to rendering a template into a string and not just in the browser. My solution for the template problem was something along these lines:

```
  action_controller = ActionController::Base.new()

  action_controller.class_eval do
    def protect_against_forgery?
      false
    end
  end

  file_string = action_controller.render_to_string('/some_template/template_file',locals: { local_variable: 1 }
```