# Render form inside email rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, form-for

I am trying to embed a form inside mailer template. The code looks somewhat like this. I have scaffolded a sample app.

rails g scaffold Listing name description

I have created a mailer class called UserNotifier and it looks something like this

```
class UserNotifier < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "from@example.com"

  def status_email(tenant, project)
    @tenant = tenant
    @project = project
    mail(to: 'abc@example.com', subject: 'Sample Status Email')
  end
end
```

And in the corresponding view to the method status_email i.e., my status_email.html.erb file would look like this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hi </h1>
    <p>
      Sample status mail sent using smtp.
    </p>
      <%= form_for [@tenant, @project], url: {controller: "listings", action: "create"}, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal project" } do |f| %>
              <% if @project.errors.any? %>
                <div id="error_expl" class="panel panel-danger">
                  <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title"><%= pluralize(@project.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this project from being saved:</h3>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul>
                    <% @project.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                      <li><%= msg %></li>
                    <% end %>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              <% end %>

              <div class="control-group">
                <%= f.label :title, :class => 'control-label' %>
                <div class="controls">
                  <%= f.text_field :title, :class => 'form-control' %>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="control-group">
                <%= f.label :details, :class => 'control-label' %>
                <div class="controls">
                  <%= f.text_field :details, :class => 'form-control' %>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="control-group">
                <%= f.label :expected_completion_date, :class => 'control-label' %>
                <div class="controls">
                  <%= f.text_field :expected_completion_date, :class => 'form-control datepicker' %>
                </div>
              </div>

              <br />
                  <%= f.hidden_field :tenant_id, value: @tenant.id, :class => 'form-control' %>
                  <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
                  <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                            root_path, :class => 'btn btn-default' %>


      <% end %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Finally I am calling the mailer method in my listings controller, create action. And here is the code snippet:

def create

```
@listing = Listing.new(listing_params)
@project = @listing.project
@tenant = @project.tenant
@user = current_user
respond_to do |format|
  if @listing.save
    UserNotifier.status_email(@tenant, @project).deliver
    format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @listing }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

But finally when I submit, I am getting this error(`NoMethodError in Listings#create`).

**`undefined method protect_against_forgery? for #<#<Class..."`**

Can somebody please help me on how to render this form in my email template such a way that user can submit this form directly from the email without having to login into the application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [undefined method \`protect\_against\_forgery?' for #<#<Class:0x0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672375/undefined-method-protect-against-forgery-for-class0x0)

Comment: Or the alternative is to use a get request with a long and hard to duplicate token. Not perfectly restful, but it does circumvent CSRF protection in a better way

Answer (score 0):

This is protect_against_forgery error you can resolve it by add in your controller

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [YOUR ACTION]
```