# ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `protect_against_forgery?' for #<#<Class:0x85f1220>:0x85fa808>):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using devise gem in an api service got the error

I have searched but not helpfull

[undefined method `protect_against_forgery?' for #<#<Class:0x0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16672375/undefined-method-protect-against-forgery-for-class0x0)

I did

```
class UsersSessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  before_action :resource
  before_action :resource_name
  before_action :devise_mapping
  before_action :protect_against_forgery?

  def new
    super
  end

  def create
    super
  end

  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end

  def protect_against_forgery?
    true
  end
end
```

then routes

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => "users_sessions"}
  resources :users_sessions
```

also generate views in locally.

Please help

I also see

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/4003

My view

### Log in

```
<%= form_for(:user, url: new_users_session_path) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <%# if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
      <%= f.label :remember_me %>
    </div>
  <%# end -%>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Remove the mark...  From both places. You can't have a symbol with a `?`

Comment: @RubyRacer You can have a `?` at the end of symbol names, just like you can in method names. Try it!

Comment: @carpetsmoker wow!

Comment: @RubyRacer which symbol you are talking ?